# backbone.js - routes with required query

Tags: backbone.js, url-routing

Is there any way to activate a backbone.js route ONLY if there's a query?

Simple Example - I need to ensure that

```
somepage?*params : "some func"
```

does not trigger `some func` when visiting `/somepage`

Obviously I could break out of the function if there are no params, but I'm looking for an answer that will simply reformat the route.

Answer (score 0):

So first let us assume that you are using the routes hash on the an extended router:

```
var MyRouter = Router.extend({
  routes: {
    'somepage?*params': 'someevent'
  }
});

var myRouter = new MyRouter();
myRouter.on("all", function(){console.log(arguments)}); // this will allow us to see a hit
Backbone.history.start();
myRouter.navigate("somepage", {trigger: true}); // => nothing
myRouter.navigate("somepage?test=1", {trigger: true}); // => ['someevent', 'test=1']
```

This should prove that it works as you would expect.